# Reading a file from a hard drive in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, file, ios-simulator

Is it possible to read a file (from my normal file system) into a iPhone App running on the iPhone Simulator?

I understand that the iPhone itself has not got a (user accessible) file system but this is simply for testing and will only ever be run in the simulator.

The file will be a text file that can be edited while the application is running, it will be read every-time a method is called.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can, and it doesn't matter where it is. Just give it an absolute path name when you load it (Xcode won't recognize a different working directory when running the simulator).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can if your file is within your app folder
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/ [your app folder] /Documents

Comment: It should be noted that this is identical to what you can do on the iPhone, i.e. NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can in general (I just tested it) - why does it have to be in the /Documents folder?

Comment: because it's easier to switch to device

Answer (score 0):

No.  Your app is running in its own sandbox on the phone.  It's not allowed to read or write outside of it.

Edit: I think CiNN is correct.  As long as your code stays on the simulator, you shouldn't have problems working with a file on your local drive.

Comment: But you could make a connection (via TCP) to a little program you write to feed it the data.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that the easiest way would be to enter "file:///" in Safari within the simulator, if thats what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It should also be noted that you can do this in reverse -- you can grab the files off your hard drive that your application created in the simulator.  This is a good way to check out your results (data, images, whatever) without having to build a data "viewer" into the application.

Answer (score 0):

FYI 'newer' sds versions will do this...  Search for iPad and you will find it. (for obvious reasons I cannot give more details here) good luck.