# Allow strings larger than 2000 characters to be passed to iOS App via xcrum simctl openurl command

Tags: ios, xcrun

I have came across the following issue and I am not sure how to get around it:
I am passing html content to an iOS app via the xcrun simctl openurl command.
Command looks like the following:
 `xcrun simctl openurl <Simulator Id> 'MyAppName://content=<Large base64 encoded html string>'`

When I parse the string in the app it has already being truncated, it seems to be happening when xcrun passes the `'MyAppName://content=<Large base64 encoded html string>` to the App.

Is there a configuration that I can update to allow larger strings to be passed as part of the openurl command in simctl?

Answer (score 0):

In general no.

This is probably related with [max URL length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers). I suggest you instead of sending data via URL try to create separate file in local file system and send in the URL path to this file. In Simulator you will have [access to this file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811924/reading-a-file-from-a-hard-drive-in-iphone-simulator) (but not tested by myself).